# Find second occurrence of pattern in regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

my inputs is

```
  String t1 = "test1:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test')";
  String t2 = "test2:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test', 'defValue')";
  String patternString = "\('.*',\s*('.*:.*').*\)";
```

I try to capture only text between second pair of ' ', ie: ns2:test
my pattern is : ('.*',\s*('.*:.*').*) and for first string it is ok,but for second i got as result: 'ns2:test', 'defValue'

Comment: Looks like `"\\('[^',]*',\\s*('[^',]*:[^',]*')"` should work for you. Or `"\\('.*?',\\s*('.*?:.*?').*\\)"`.

Comment: ok, let's make it more complex 
String t3 = "test2:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test', 'defValue') = test2:testVar('varName', 'ns1:test111', 'defValue') ";
 i need to capture ns2:test and ns1:test111 –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make all parts of your pattern lazy:

```
\('.*?',\s*('.*?:.*?').*?\)
   ^^^       ^^^ ^^^  ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO1eT8/3).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/SOzzlx):

```
String t1 = "test1:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test')";
String t2 = "test2:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test', 'defValue')";
String patternString = "\\('.*?',\\s*('.*?:.*?').*?\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t1);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(t2);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

An alternative is to use negated character classes, but it may cause issues if your input is more complex than what you posted:

```
\('[^',]*',\s*('[^',]*:[^',]*')
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO1eT8/2), where `[^',]` matches any character but a `'` and `,`.

Comment: hm, it's working correct ! Thank You. 
Is there more simple regex ?

Comment: Even simpler? Do not use "complex" regex, use a basic one for string splitting.

Comment: ok,
let's make it more complex
String t3 = "test2:testVar('varName', 'ns2:test', 'defValue') = test2:testVar('varName', 'ns1:test111', 'defValue') ";

i need to capture ns2:test and ns1:test111

Comment: Just [replace the last `.*` with `[^)]*`](http://ideone.com/Gfhs4p). Or make it lazy again.

Answer (score 0):

If fragments of strings you want to capture always looks similar to given examples, try with:

```
'\w+:\w+'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aI1qC4/1)

Comment: so instead `\w+` you can use character group with special chars, like `[\w%^&]`, but it is up to you