# Extract Only the Second Instance of Pattern in Regex

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the second instance of a pattern from a string using regexes in the programming language `R`, version 4.0.2 and the `stringr` package.

```
> test_string <- "Viscocity                      S   <=0.25        S   <=0.25 Levorotatory                      S      <=21        R      <=2.5 Giminal                    S      <=1        S      <=1"
```

I have the following regex which can pull the first pattern (specifically for Levorotatory):

```
regex <- "(\\s*(?:S|R|I|N/I)(\\s*\\W*\\d*\\.?\\d?\\d?\\d?\\s*))"
str_trim(str_extract_all(test_string, glue('(?<=Levorotatory){regex}')))
```

Which gives me the output:

```
"S      <=21"
```

But I want to grab the **second pattern**: `R      <=2.5`
So far, I have been able to pull both patterns using a quantifier:

```
regex <- "(\\s*(?:S|R|I|N/I)(\\s*\\W*\\d*\\.?\\d?\\d?\\d?\\s*)){2}"
str_trim(str_extract_all(test_string, glue('(?<=Levorotatory){regex}')))
output: "S      <=21        R      <=2.5"
```

This is is not exactly what I was looking for.

My question: **Can I grab only the second instance of a regex pattern?**

There are a handful of similar posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064470/find-second-occurrence-of-pattern-in-regex), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349946/how-to-match-everything-up-to-the-second-occurrence-of-a-character), but I tried fiddling with these solutions with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a pattern like below with `str_match`:

```
(?<=Levorotatory)(?:\s*([SRI]|N/I)\s*([^\w\s]*\d*\.?\d+)){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSoD02/1). You may control which match you get with `{X}` at the end. Details:

- `(?<=Levorotatory)` - right before the current location, there must be `Levorotatory` (note you may just use `Levorotatory` here)
- `(?:\s*([SRI]|N/I)\s*([^\w\s]*\d*\.?\d+)){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `([SRI]|N/I)` - `S`, `R`, `I` or `N/I`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `([^\w\s]*\d*\.?\d+)` - zero or more punctuation chars other than `_`, 0+ digits, an optional `.` and one or more digits.

See [an R demo](https://ideone.com/e8TTb0):

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- "(?<=Levorotatory)(?:\\s*([SRI]|N/I)\\s*([^\\w\\s]*\\d*\\.?\\d+)){2}";
x <- "Viscocity                      S   <=0.25        S   <=0.25 Levorotatory                      S      <=21        R      <=2.5 Giminal                    S      <=1        S      <=1"
results <- str_match(x, pattern)[,-1]
results
# => [1] "R"     "<=2.5"
```